# Calculating a min (vector) of a function in python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i have to find a minimum of a function **containing matrices and vectors**-

[image]

[image]
is a matrix and y is a vector. w is what i am trying to minimize (it's a vector)].

Is there a way to calculate w given X and y? Some function that can outputs a "minimal vector"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to solve X.w=y in an approximate way (the transposition in your equation is trivial). There's a standard function for that:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Quoting: `numpy.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=-1)` ... Solves the equation a x = b by computing a vector x that minimizes the Euclidean 2-norm || b - a x ||^2. The equation may be under-, well-, or over- determined ...

Comment: EXACLY what i've been looking for!